# C get difference string and integer

Tags: c

Hi I am new in C programming, currently I start my simple app of getting user input, now how can I get input from user and differentiate whether user input containing string, integer or combination of both.

I have tried the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char * s = "CPROGRAMMING";
    int i;
    boolean flag = true;
    for(i = 0;, i < strlen(s) && flag == true; i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(s[i]) && isupper(s[i])) flag = true;
        else flag = false;
    }
    if(flag) printf("A string contains only uppercase and alphabet letters\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But it seems fails in finding the right inputs. What am I missing here?

Comment: what is `boolean` ?! How it fails, compile error?

Comment: What is the problem here? What is failing?

Comment: yes boolean return an error

Comment: Because it doesn't exist in C. Look into `<stdbool.h>`

Comment: @SaraswathiApavoo: C has no 'boolean' type. C++ has `bool`, and maybe that's what you meant. But this is otherwise not at all a C++ program. Later versions of the C standard have `_Bool` and if you include `<stdbool.h>` you get a `#define` that sets `bool` to `_Bool` so you can use `bool`, `true`, and `false` mostly like you use them in C++.

Comment: @Omnifarious C has the type `_Bool`. Most prefer to use the macro `bool` found in stdbool.h, which expands to `_Bool`.

Comment: @Lundin: I sort of thought something like that had been added. I fixed my comment. :-) Thanks!

Comment: Remove that comma from your for loop condition...

Answer (score 1):

Some of the issues:

- To get user input, use `scanf`.
- C doesn't have `boolean`, did you mean `int`?
- Your loop is redundant, you only check the last letter anyway - well, you check all, but only the last one is taken into account when you set the flag the last time. You can break execution from the loop when you want with a `break`.
- The condition in the loop has a stray `,`.

Answer (score 1):

You code has some syntax problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* s = "CPROGRAMMING";
    int i;
    bool flag = true;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s) && flag; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(s[i]) && isupper(s[i]))
            flag = true;
        else
            flag = false;
    }
    if (flag)
        printf("A string contains only uppercase and alphabet letters\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing `<stdbool.h>` to use the macro `bool` that evaluates to `_Bool`.

Comment: not works still return errors test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:10:5: error: unknown type name ‘bool’
test.c:10:17: error: ‘true’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:10:17: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
test.c:16:20: error: ‘false’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: And, while this isn't a syntax error, I consider `flag == true` to be terrible style. It should just be `flag`.

Comment: Using the macro in `<stdbool.h>` is imo much easier and natural, but I guess this works too.

Comment: @MM. how is char s contain integer?

Comment: @Rapptz: You're right. I can not reject your suggestion. Updated.

Comment: @MM. can i parse user inputs into char * s ? using gets() function?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    (void) argc;
    (void) argv;

    const char* s = "CPROGRAMMING";
    bool upper_case = true;
    for (int i = 0; i<strlen(s) && upper_case ; i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(s[i]) || !isupper(s[i]))
        {
            upper_case = false;
        }
    }

    if (upper_case)
    {
        printf("A string contains only uppercase and alphabet letters\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Fixes:

- Included correct headers.
- Using correct bool type.
- Cleared up boolean logic.
- Fixed code formatting.
- Declaring a pointer to string literal correctly.
- Made it clear that the parameters to main are not used.

Comment: how can i parse user inputs using gets() to char * s?

Comment: buddy your code got an error : test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:13:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
test.c:13:5: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code

Comment: @SaraswathiApavoo You have to compile with a real C compiler. If you are using GCC, do as it says, compile with `gcc code.c -std=c99`.

Comment: @SaraswathiApavoo As for gets, it is a very bad function which has been removed from the C language, don't use it. If you have separate questions regarding user input, please post a new question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: it keeps repeating when integer is past to char * s as follow: A string contains integers
A string contains integers
A string contains integers
A string contains integers
How can i decide only once not many times?